Can you shove or reposition an ally?
I'm running the PF2 remaster beginner box adventure Menace Under Otari. In one of the fights, the fighter asked if he could use the reposition action on one of the other PCs, to get them out of melee range of the enemies. The other PC was willing to be moved, so as a one-off ruling I had the fighter make the roll against the other PC's fortitude DC and allowed the movement when they passed the roll.
Given that shove and reposition are attack actions, I assume this isn't what they're intended for, but is there any reason they wouldn't be able to use them on allies? If they can't, is there another action the PCs can use to move each other around?

Yes, you can.
Shove and reposition both specify "a creature" rather than "an opponent," so they can both be used on allies. As you ruled, they would still need to overcome their target's fortitude DC, since there's no clause in either action that would allow a target to willingly be affected.
There aren't any other generic actions that would allow a character to reposition their allies although there are some feats, such as Friendly Toss, that would allow a character to reposition allies.
Note that there is an optional rule that would allow for the ally to allow you to make your degree of success one better; see Can you opt to fail a saving throw?.
